# Sublime global file search: interpret `::` as `/`

Tags: ruby, sublimetext3, file-search

In Ruby, namespaces are separated by `::` (e.g.: `Services::ProductService`), and it's good practice to keep the file system structure consistent (e.g. above: `services/product_service.rb`.

When looking up a class file using `cmd+T`, it would be very handy if `::` were excluded by the search, or even better, considered like folder delimiters `/`, so that pasting `Services::ProductService` in the search could match `services/product_service.rb`.

Is this possible?

Comment: You could script the `subl` command-line shortcut, possibly.

Comment: Ruby seems unrelated here... it's more about sublime.

Comment: `Cmd+O` is `File > Open`, which is a native OS open file dialog. If you meant `Cmd+P` (`Goto > Anything`), the best you can do is just not enter the `::` at all. Generally speaking though if you're putting whole filenames into the Goto Anything panel you're not using it to it's full capabilities.

Comment: OH! Thank you, it was `cmd+T` - updated (: